# HTML Background Scrolling Effect

Tags: javascript, css, html, scroll

Happened to come across an e-commerce website today, [Harrods.com](http://www.harrods.com). I thought the scrolling effects that they are using (non-mobile site) are really cool. The content and backgrounds seem to scroll at different rates. As you scroll the navigation selector moves under the appropriate category as well.

I tried going through their source to figure out how they are doing it but didn't have any luck. I saw that they loaded up the background images in a `homeImages` variable, but never found it used in a script. Is this something that can be accomplished purely with CSS? Is there a name for this effect I can search on?

Comment: Google parallax scrolling.. it is similar to that.

Comment: Here's another one you might like: http://events.jquery.org/2013/eu/

Comment: @frenchie: That just looks like an ordinary scroll.

Comment: http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/

Comment: @RobertHarvey:keep scrolling. See the plane?

Comment: Thanks for the info. Had never heard of parallax scrolling before. Add it as an answer and I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find **parallax scrolling** helpful. Search for it in Google and you will find various tutorials on the subject.

Helpful link provided by @RobertHarvey http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/

Answer (score 2):

The effect they are using is called Parallax.

It is a JS driven special effect that let's you attach a scroll rate to individual elements on the page.

There are a few popular Parallax libraries out there depending on your needs:

**[Stellar.js](http://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/)** This library is jQuery based, it supports horizontal & vertical scrolling. It also has experimental support for iOS mobile devices.

**[Parallax-JS](https://github.com/razorfish/Parallax-JS)** This library is also jQuery dependent, but is perhaps a little more minimal in it's features, and a little easier to implement.

**[jparallax](http://stephband.info/jparallax/)** Also jQuery driven, similar to Parallax-JS, but offers a few more options for tweaking effects.

**[Super Scroll Orama](http://johnpolacek.github.io/superscrollorama/)** Also a jQuery plugin (sensing the theme yet?) this scroll effect library is specifically animation focused, and offers cool options with that in mind.

If you want even more info checkout this [list of tutorials/libraries](http://medleyweb.com/web-dev/15-useful-jquery-parallax-plugins-and-tutorials/).